# Obtaining Pareto front for more than 2 objectives

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I have a reasonably tractable problem withe >2 objectives in which I apply multi-objective evolutionary algorithms (MOEA) like PSO, ACO, GA.

I would like to compare the performance and quality of the Pareto produced by these algorithms against the Pareto front.

Since the range of the variables in the problem can be enumerated, and provided that the problem is tractable I am thinking to use brute force to obtain the Pareto front to make the comparison against the MOEAs.

However, it's not clear yet how to obtain the Pareto front using brute force? Is it possible to use dominance ranking in brute force?

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

**Example**

Consider a simplified instance of a multi-objective problem with:

1. Integer variables x,y,z  in [1,100]
2. Objectives: objA, objB, objC

The goal is to run brute-force on x,y,z and evaluate objA,objB,objC and generate the Pareto front.

Comment: Generally there are data structures that maintain a set of points under insertion/deletion and allow enumerating the front in polylogarithmic time (+ number of minima, of course). If you have a static set, you should be able to strip off a few log factors using range trees (i.e. O(n log^(d-2) n) to find the minima in d dimensions). What is it that you need exactly?

Comment: @NiklasB. I updated the question giving a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. Do you have in mind what data structures might be useful?

Comment: I think you misuse the term brute-force, which causes some confusion here. For the static 3-d case you can just sort the points in one dimension, scan them and insert them into a balanced binary search tree for the 2-d dominance checks. That algorithm will be O(n log n). For d > 3 it becomes more complicated if you want linearithmic runtime

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NiklasB. Well, brute-force means to examine all the possible values for x,y,z (i.e., the cartesian product), do the evaluation and find the optimal solution or in the case of multiple objectives to generate the Pareto front.

Comment: Well yes, but how you obtain the data points is totally irrelevant. You can generalize the problem to something like "given a set of points S = { (x_i, y_i, z_i) |  0 <= i < n }, find the set of points that are not dominated by any other point in the set" or something like that. Where the points come from doesn't make a difference, unless there is some additional conditions like correlation or restricted value range etc., which you don't mention.

Comment: Is there any source/pseudocode where I can take a look for the cases of d=3  && d>3?

Comment: [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1392.pdf) has an overview over historical methods to find the pareto optima of a static set.

Comment: Well, there are some additional constraints but for the sake of simplicity we can consider that we are given (as you correctly mentioned) a set of points S = { (x_i, y_i, z_i) | 0 <= i < n,  low_x <= x_i <= high_x (similarly for y &z)}. From this set we want to extract the Pareto front. This is the task.

Comment: the paper I linked to has lots of references to traditional algorithms for the problem and even for the special case of the solution space arising in MOEA optimization

Comment: thanks for the paper, I'm looking at it right now. there are some interesting algorithms indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a running set of Pareto-optimal points and incrementally update it as you observe each new point. In practice this can perform much better than generating all points and then doing a brute force O(n<sup>2</sup>) calculation to find the Pareto-optimal ones.

Here's some Python code to demonstrate the idea.

```
S = {}
def update(p):
  if any(q > p for q in S):
    return
  for q in [q for q in S if p > q]:
    S.remove(q)
  S.add(p)
```

If the average size of `S` over n updates is k, then the complexity is O(nk).

Comment: Thanks @Timothy. Unfortunately I cannot update the Pareto front on-the-fly as I need to create first the cartesian product of my variables and then to extract the Pareto front. In principle this will work for any number of objectives, isn't it?

Comment: @STiGMa I don't understand your comment.  This approach works for any number of objectives.

Comment: With on-the-fly I mean incrementally. Since brute-force will be used for comparing the MOEAs, I have to generate all the points first and then run a brute-force to find the Pareto front.

Comment: Any answers to this questions?